# Is it a hardware failure to have badblocks on HDD

Tags: hard-drive, bad-blocks

My PC was running slow , I thought that there may be some problem with the hard disk , so I ran `badblocks` and the process was running for the last 263 hours before I accidentally interrupted it. It has reported 4133 errors. I've attached the [error logs](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d51ea90e0dc2583fe3e1)

does it mean that my hard disk is broken and I need to buy a new one?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a very likely sign of a failing hard drive. I would suggest to back up your data immediately if you haven't already and replace this, as even if it hasn't completely failed at this stage, it will become harder to recover data further down the line.

It IS possible the fault is repairable, but in all honesty with this amount of errors I wouldn't take the chance. You can check the SMART data reports and see what this reports for 'Reallocated Sector Count'. This indicates the number of bad sectors reallocated to redundant sectors on the disk. Usually you'd only start noticing real problems when these redundant sectors are already allocated.

Comment: Definitely check SMART like Jonno Said, I like HDTune for checking HDD status, it shows a lot and I have never had it run for 263 hours.  It can give you a pretty good idea and it only takes minutes